# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException - Could not extract result set using JOINED inheritance strategy

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I created hierarchy of two entities, which i implement using the JOINED inheritance strategy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "procedure")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class MedicalProcedure{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Date time;
    
    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id")
    private Doctor doctor;
    
    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
            )
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private Patient patient;
        
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "procedure_single")
public class DentalProcedure extends MedicalProcedure
{   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;
}
```

Problem occurs, when I try to get all of the DentalProcedures using getAll method from my generic DAO:

```
@Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        Session session = currentSession();
        
        CriteriaQuery<? extends T> cq = session.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(daoType);
        cq.from(daoType);
        
        List<? extends T> list = session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        
        return (List<T>) list;
    }
```

(*) daoType: class com.xyz.clinic.domain.DentalProcedure

Hibernate generates the following sql:

```
Hibernate:  
select 

dentalproc0_.id as id1_2_, 
dentalproc0_1_.date as date2_2_, 
dentalproc0_1_.doctor_id as doctor_i4_2_, 
dentalproc0_1_.patient_id as patient_5_2_, 
dentalproc0_1_.time as time3_2_, dentalproc0_.data as data1_3_

from procedure_single dentalproc0_ inner join procedure dentalproc0_1_ on dentalproc0_.id=dentalproc0_1_.id
```

But after that, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'procedure dentalproc0_1_ on dentalproc0_.id=dentalproc0_1_.id' at line 1
```

Here are the sql statements i used to create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `procedure` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `patient_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doctor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_PATIENT_ID_idx` (`patient_id`),
  KEY `FK_PATIENT_ID_idx1` (`doctor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DOCTOR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`doctor_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PATIENT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `procedure_single` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `PK_SINGLE_PROCEDURE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `procedure` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I can't find the problem. Could anybody explain to me what is happening and how do i deal with this?

Comment: I would guess that the problem is caused by `PROCEDURE` being a reserved word in MySQL.  Try escaping it: see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers .

Comment: i've changed it and couple other details, following one of the Vlad Mihalcea's tutorials, and it worked. Thanks for help @LukeWoodward, I don't think i would come up with something of that type :)